# Analyzing data with Excel [Python]

Tags: python, excel

I'm a beginner in Python and as an exercize, I'm trying to run some basic statistical tests on some data that I have. The data is saved in an Excel file and it is structured in this way:

```
1   4   h   2,882233356 1,5 h   1
2   3   b   0,786094826 1   b   1
3   4   h   0,726763523 1   h   1
4   7   b   0,906494312 1,5 b   1
```

I'm having some problems in parsing these numbers: what I need is a way to extract the reaction times (column 4) based on the condition (column 2).

Therefore, I need something like this:

```
4 2,882233356   
3 0,786094826   
4 0,726763523
7 0,906494312
```

And extract the mean (and all the other statistics) of the RTs based on the condition (RTs for condition 4, RTs for condition 3 and so on).

I tried different approaches, but can't figure it out :S

Thank you for your help!